# How to pre-fill Django dynamically added formset fields on HTML page

Tags: django, django-forms, rendering, inline-formset

I am using Django inline formset with option to add additional forms at runtime. Some of the fields display the default values as already defined in the related models. However, when new rows of formsets are added, most of the fields are "blank" (i.e. the default values do not show up in those fields), except the date field which show the date widget.

[image]

As in the image above, a new row containing the blank (red rectangle) field fails to show the default value (as otherwise available in the rows available at page load).

I am currently using jQuery to fill the blank fields capturing the "rowadded" function but find it quite a mess, as managing the code is cumbersome.

Is there a ready to use function/plugin available in Django which can be used to fill the fields on addition of new row/s (at runtime)?

Answer (score 0):

When you render the form, i.e. `form = MyForm()`, specify the instance of the form like so:

`form = MyForm(instance=Model.objects.get(pk=1)`.

This will populate your form with the object from Model with a primary key of 1.

Comment: I don't get it. Read my query again. What I am looking to do is to have the new (dynamically added) form field to "contain" the `default=` value declared for the field in model definition.